# How to check is the table exists or not in MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

thats what I'm doing:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ".$db_name." AND table_name = users");
$nr = $result->num_rows; // 77 line
var_dump($nr);
$mysqli->close();
```

But the errors says:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 77
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also check by using this statement `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tablename';`

Answer (score 1):

For your method to work, you need quotes around the string constants:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = '".$db_name."' AND table_name = 'users';
```

However, for your method to really work, do this:

```
SELECT 1
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = '".$db_name."' AND table_name = 'users';
```

You are looking at the number of rows being returned, not the value of `count(*)`.

Comment: done, the result is always `int(1)` even if I write `usersssssss`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE FALSE;
```

**:-)**

*Success means table exists, failure... means it doesn't!*